# conjecture formula/prove by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Conjecture formula from following equations, and prove conjecture:
$1=1,\\2+3+4=1+8,\\5+6+7+8+9=8+27,\\10+11+12+13+14+15+16=27+64\\$

$S(n)=\sum_{i=(n-1)^2+1}^{n^2}i=(n-1)^3+n^3$

$S(1)=1=1\\S(2)=2+3+4=1+8\\S(3)=5+6+7+8+9=8+27\\S(4)=10+11+12+13+14+15+16=27+64$

Need to show $S(n+1)=\sum_{i=n^2+1}^{(n+1)^2}i=n^3+(n+1)^3$?  Not sure.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that (we can prove it using Gauss method)
$$\sum_{k=p}^q k=\frac{(q-p+1)(p+q)}2$$
so we find that

$$S(n)=\frac{(n^2-(n-1)^2)(n^2+(n-1)^2+1)}{2}=2\,{n}^{3}−3\,{n}^{2}+3\,n−1\\=n^3+(n-1)^3$$

Comment: No need for induction?  I think I am supposed to prove it using induction.  I guess not if Gauss is already proven using induction?

Answer (score 0):

How about
\begin{align}
  S(n) &=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}i - \sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)^2}i\\
       &=\dfrac{n^2(n^2+1)}2 - \dfrac{[(n-1)^2]\,[(n-1)^2 + 1]}2 \\
       &=\dfrac{n^4+n^2}2 - \dfrac{(n-1)^4 + (n-1)^2}2 \\
       &=\dfrac{n^4-(n-1)^4+n^2-(n-1)^2}2 \\
       &=\dfrac{(n^2-(n-1)^2)(n^2+(n-1)^2)+(n-(n-1))(n+(n-1))}2 \\
       &=\dfrac{(2n-1)(2n^2-2n+1)+(2n-1)}2 \\
       &=\dfrac{(2n-1)(2n^2-2n+2)}2 \\
       &=(2n-1)(n^2-n+1) \\
       &=2n^3 -3n^2 + 3n - 1 \\
       &=n^3 + (n^3 - 3n^2 + 3n - 1) \\
       &=n^3 + (n-1)^3 \\
\end{align}